# Does maven enforcer ignore dependencyManagement section?

Tags: maven, maven-enforcer-plugin

I have specified a version of a library in imported dependencyManagement section of a parent pom. I confirmed that my effective pom has only one occurence of this dependency. It is in dependencyManagement section:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>[3.18.1-GA]</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

That should override version for transitive dependencies depending on it. After installing (and reinstalling dependencies to match version bounds), org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree prints:

```
org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile (version selected from constraint [3.18.1-GA,3.18.1-GA])
```

But (originally, without reinstalling dependencies) enforcer complains about wrong version:

```
[WARNING] Rule 1: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.DependencyConvergence failed with message:
Failed while enforcing releasability the error(s) are [
Dependency convergence error for org.javassist:javassist:3.18.2-GA paths to dependency are:
...
```

And shows that first transitive dependency uses

```
org.javassist:javassist:3.18.2-GA
```

Which comes from dependency that in turn depends on:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.18.2-GA</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and another uses

```
org.javassist:javassist:3.18.1-GA
```

Why is enforcer inconsistent with dependency tree? What could be wrong? If I use version bounds, will they be respected and I can skip using enforcer for this purpose?

Also, adding dependency to project module in question does not change anything.

Answer (score 6):

**Tl;dr**: `dependencyManagement` overrides the version of transitive dependencies

All the credit for this answer goes to Andy Dennie whose blog post I stumbled upon:
https://www.fizz-buzz.com/blog/2012/08/02/maven-enforcer-plugin-vs-dependencymanagement

`dependencyManagement` does two things - one of which is well known and the other is rarely mentioned.

1. Set a default version for dependencies in submodules/child projects
2. override the version of transitive dependencies

So the enforcer plugin does not ignore the `dependencyManagement`. But is unable to recognize the discrepancy since the transitive dependency's version was altered before it went to work. Andy Denny has a good suggestion on his blog on how to proceed:

> 1. I don’t put dependencies in the dependencyManagement section of my top-level POM.  I want to be alerted by maven-enforcer-plugin when I’ve got mismatches.  Instead, I use version properties, as mentioned in my approach #1 above.
> 2. When maven-enforcer-plugin notifies me of discrepancies, I try to see if I can get the artifacts involved to use the same version of the divergent dependency.  If all the dependencies involved are in my own artifacts, I try to get them aligned on the same version of the dependency.  If some artifacts are mine and some are from 3rd parties, I try to align my dependencies with the 3rd parties, and/or look for other versions of the 3rd party artifacts that have dependency versions that align with each other, and my code.
> 3. If after doing the above, I still have unresolveable discrepancies, I choose what I think is the “best fit” version of the problematic artifact and specify that in the dependencyManagement section of the project POM where maven-enforcer-plugin reported the problem (not in my top-level POM).  I add a comment to the dependency declaration in that POM noting the issue and the workaround, so that in the future, should I upgrade to a newer version of the dependency, I’ll see the note and can revisit whether the discrepancy can possibly then be resolved.

The trade-off here is that you have a working enforcer plugin that helps you with dependency hell, but have to do more by hand.